# ColdFusion loop condition attribute

Tags: coldfusion, attributes

I have a variable `<cfset takeFour = 0 >`. I then have a loop that I want to run 4 times.

```
<cfloop query="getVids" condition="takeFour LTE 4">
                <cfset takeFour= takeFour + 1/>...
```

The CF debugger says that there is a attribute validation error for this tag, however this syntax should be correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using cfloop to loop over a query, the acceptable attributes are, query, startRow, and endRow. Condition is not used when query is, which is why the complier is giving you an attribute validation error.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_10.html

Comment: +1 correct answer assuming `takeFour` is not incremented according to some conditional algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the condition attribute on a cfloop with a query attribute, you can, however, break out of a loop when your condition is met. You could do this:

```
<cfloop query="getVids">
    <cfset takeFour = takeFour + 1 />

    <cfif takeFour GT 4>
        <cfbreak />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Of course, if you just want to loop over the first four rows, you can do this:

```
<cfloop query="getVids" startrow="1" endrow="4">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Short, thank you for showing me the cfbreak tag, that is good to know.